# Change Mime Type of Uploaded PDFs in Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, mime-types

I have a number of PDFs that have been uploaded to Google Drive manually. Most were appropriately recognized as PDFs and the mime types were set accordingly. A few were not. This appears to be an issue with FireFox.

I can download/re-upload (in Chrome) and they get recognized as PDFs so the issue isn't with the file itself. I realize I can do that manually but I'm looking for a way to fix this automatically via a script.

`file.getMimeType` for the failing files returns `application/download` rather than `application/pdf`

I'd like to change the mime type for these files to `application/pdf` via Google Script but I can't find a method to do that. I've looked through the Drive App methods for files but can't find a way to do it.

`setMimeType` doesn't seem to be an option for files like it is for blobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate over files ending in ".pdf" and not of the correct mimetype and create a copy of them using the DriveApp method:

[`.createFile('new' +name, content, mimeType);`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createFile(String,String,String))

The input "content" coming from a [`getBlob()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getBlob()) method.

Then delete the original file.

Then rename the copy to remove the 'new', if desired.

Without seeing your code structure and directory structure of your Drive, it's hard (for me) to write generic code, but this should help. I hope!